# Is there a difference between .change() and .on("change")?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any difference between :

`$('selector').change(function() {});`

and

`$('selector').on("change", function() {});`

And if there is, which one should I use in most cases?

Comment: No difference, and use whichever you prefer

Comment: I think no difference

Comment: i think `click` work on already exits elements and `onclick` also work with dynamically generated elements

Comment: @AnujKhandelwal You need to pass selector parameter to `on()` method to delegate it. This is not the case here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is no difference at all, they both trigger the same javascript function. You can use both in any browser that supports the  `addEventListener` modules.

Check the list of browsers that support it: http://caniuse.com/#feat=addeventlistener

However to remove the event, you'll have to use `.off( "change" )`
as the [jquery doc](https://api.jquery.com/change/) suggests

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

No difference, internally `change` function would use `.on(...)` to bind the respective event.

```
function (data, fn) {
    return arguments.length > 0 ? this.on(name, null, data, fn) : this.trigger(name);
}
```

### [Source](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=jQuery.fn.change)

Answer (score 1):

in accordance to method documentation `$('selector').change( function() {})` is just a shortcut for `$('selector').on("change", function() {});`. indeed this is the same.